# Save data in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment which shows some deals fetched from the server through ViewModel class. My question is i every time i navigate through BottomNavigation each time my fragments gets replaced and all the data fetches again, i have a progress bar which appears when the data is fetching from the service, i'm calling all my data inside ViewModel class then through the object of that ViewModel class i'm setting that data in my fragment, is there any way to store the data coming from the object of viewModel class inside onSavedInstanceState of the fragment to restore it when the fragment is created again. I know int, strings values gets stored in onSavedInstanceState but dont know how to save data coming from a viewModel class.

Comment: can post your code here, for better understanding

Comment: you likely need to store the data somewhere out of the fragment for it not to be destroyed with fragment.